# Celery - Supervisor Not working properly

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, supervisord

```
time_for_next_iteration_in_seconds = 60 * 5


@app.task(bind=True)
def assign_user(self, hangout_id):
    hangout = Hangout.objects.get(id=hangout_id)
    if hangout.has_claimed:
        app.control.revoke(task_id=self.request.id)

    total_tickets = HangoutSubscription.objects.filter(
        hangout=hangout, is_processed=False).aggregate(
        total_tickets=Sum('entries'))['total_tickets']
    if total_tickets > 0:
        winner_ticket = random.randint(1, total_tickets)
        user = find_alloted_user(hangout, winner_ticket)
        alloted_user = ChampUser.objects.get(id=user[1])

        #  send mail to allotted user
        content, subject = allotment_email_content_subject(
            alloted_user.id, hangout.id)
        Thread(target=send_html_email, args=(
            [alloted_user.email], subject, content)).start()

        job = assign_user2.apply_async(
            (hangout_id, ), countdown=time_for_next_iteration_in_seconds,
            expires=time_for_next_iteration_in_seconds + 60)
        Hangout.objects.filter(id=hangout_id).update(
            celery_task_id=job.task_id)
        HangoutAllotmentHistory(
            user=alloted_user, hangout=hangout,
            celery_task_id=self.request.id).save()
    else:
        Hangout.objects.filter(id=hangout.id).update(is_active=False)

    app.control.revoke(task_id=self.request.id)


@app.task(bind=True)
def assign_user2(self, hangout_id):
    hangout = Hangout.objects.get(id=hangout_id)
    if hangout.has_claimed:
        app.control.revoke(task_id=self.request.id)
    else:
        failed_users = HangoutAllotmentHistory.objects.filter(
            hangout=hangout).values_list('user_id', flat=True)
        HangoutSubscription.objects.filter(
            hangout=hangout, user_id__in=failed_users).update(is_processed=True)

    total_tickets = HangoutSubscription.objects.filter(
        hangout=hangout, is_processed=False).aggregate(
        total_tickets=Sum('entries'))['total_tickets']
    if total_tickets > 0:
        winner_ticket = random.randint(1, total_tickets)
        user = find_alloted_user(hangout, winner_ticket)
        alloted_user = ChampUser.objects.get(id=user[1])

        #  send mail to allotted user
        content, subject = allotment_email_content_subject(
            alloted_user.id, hangout.id)

> Blockquote

        Thread(target=send_html_email, args=(
            [alloted_user.email], subject, content)).start()

        job = assign_user3.apply_async(
            (hangout_id, ), countdown=time_for_next_iteration_in_seconds,
            expires=time_for_next_iteration_in_seconds + 60)
        Hangout.objects.filter(id=hangout_id).update(
            celery_task_id=job.task_id)
        HangoutAllotmentHistory(
            user=alloted_user, hangout=hangout,
            celery_task_id=self.request.id).save()
    else:
        Hangout.objects.filter(id=hangout.id).update(is_active=False)

    app.control.revoke(task_id=self.request.id)


@app.task(bind=True)
def assign_user3(self, hangout_id):
    hangout = Hangout.objects.get(id=hangout_id)
    if hangout.has_claimed:
        app.control.revoke(task_id=self.request.id)
    else:
        failed_users = HangoutAllotmentHistory.objects.filter(
            hangout=hangout).values_list('user_id', flat=True)
        HangoutSubscription.objects.filter(
            hangout=hangout, user_id__in=failed_users).update(is_processed=True)

    total_tickets = HangoutSubscription.objects.filter(
        hangout=hangout, is_processed=False).aggregate(
        total_tickets=Sum('entries'))['total_tickets']
    if total_tickets > 0:
        winner_ticket = random.randint(1, total_tickets)
        user = find_alloted_user(hangout, winner_ticket)
        alloted_user = ChampUser.objects.get(id=user[1])

        #  send mail to allotted user
        content, subject = allotment_email_content_subject(
            alloted_user.id, hangout.id)
        Thread(target=send_html_email, args=(
            [alloted_user.email], subject, content)).start()

        HangoutAllotmentHistory(
            user=alloted_user, hangout=hangout,
            celery_task_id=self.request.id).save()
    else:
        Hangout.objects.filter(id=hangout.id).update(is_active=False)

    app.control.revoke(task_id=self.request.id)
```

Created 3 tasks using clery. But it is working properly in local. But in server it is not working as expected.

Supervisor conf: as suggested by https://thomassileo.name/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/

```
[program:champ]
command=/home/qa/prj/venv/bin/celery -A myworker worker -l info
stdout_logfile=/home/qa/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/home/qa/celeryd.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
```

I have installed supervisor via pip and its version in 3.3.0

My problem is that celery reload using  **supervisorctl restart champ** is not working properly. But command doesn't throw any error. (with in virtual env). What am i doing wrong. I am using celery in Django.

my celery.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('myworker', broker="redis://localhost:6379")


app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
  print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: do `sudo supervisorctl status`, is your worker 'champ' running?

Comment: also stop all supervisorctl tasks, do `ps aux | grep champ` if you find more than one worker.. kill all of them using kill command.. then restart all of them again